# ASP.NET Membership Password Recovery E-mail

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm trying to use the out-of-the-box ASP.NET PasswordRecovery control, but I want to customize the email that's sent to the user, essentially translating it for different language users.

I understand that I can specify MailDefinition-Subject and MailDefinition-BodyFileName, but what I really want to do it store all e-mails used by my site in a SharePoint list, and have each control that sends an email read the subject and body from there.

I've been able to do this for the CreateUserWizard control, but adding my own sendEMail method inside The OnCreatedUser event.

I'm wondering if I can use the OnSendingMail event, or OnVerifyingUser event to send my own email, and if I can stop this control sending it's own email by default.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Kevin